# OSX is permanently deleting files

Tags: macos

I have entered this command in terminal:

```
cd ~/.Trash
chflags -R nouchg *
```

now files won't go to trash, just they delete permanently.

how can I restore to default behavior?

[image]

Comment: Removing the entire `.Trash` folder should be enough? I don’t get how you managed to break it though. Was there something in the `.Trash` folder when you executed the command?

Comment: yes, there were some files that couldn't be deleted. the above command didn't clear the trash, but I think has done something with deleting files behavior!!! which bypass the files from going to trash! instead warn to delete them permanently. I tried this command:`sudo rm -rf ~/.Trash /Volumes/*/.Trashes` which cleared trash.

Comment: Yes, OS X falls back to deleting directly when it deems the Trash corrupted. What’s the output of `ls -lO` (that’s a lowercase L and an uppercase o) in the `.Trash` folder you can’t remove?

Comment: `-rw-r--r--@ 1 Hashem  staff  - 24116 Oct 16 16:34 icon 4.41.14 PM.ttf
-rw-r--r--@ 1 Hashem  staff  - 24116 Oct 16 16:34 icon.ttf` wow, the above command restore trash folder to its default behavior. post as an answer, to accept it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If OS X decides (on whatever basis) that the trash folder is damaged, it will fall back to (really) deleting files. That’s why you get the warning.

The `.Trash` folders don’t involve too much magic. They will also automatically be recreated should they ever go missing. That means the simplest way to restore the proper behavior is to just remove them completely. To remove your personal trash folder, use the following command:

```
rm -rf ~/.Trash
```

**This will remove all files currently in the trash folder!** You might want to move them away first. **Be very careful not to insert a space anywhere or you might wipe your entire home folder!**

From the command you performed, it would appear that files in the trash folder are normally marked as immutable. The inverse command would be:

```
chflags -R uchg *
```

Comment: thanks for answer, but I have that problem for partitions other than macintosh HD. every file on those drives are deleting permanently, without going to trash!

Comment: Other partitions or other disks? Are they internal, external or perhaps network shares? Do they even have a trash folder?

Comment: it has a 2 TB internal fusion drive. no I have not created any trash folder